# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I run my program and I have no idea why. The error is occurring on the line that says "if 1 not in c:"

Code:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0, 3],
    [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [7, 0, 8, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
a = 1
while a:
     try:
        for c, row in enumerate(matrix):
            if 0 in row:
                print("Found 0 on row,", c, "index", row.index(0))
                if 1 not in c:
                    print ("t")
    except ValueError:
         break
```

What I would like to know is how I can fix this error from happening an still have the program run correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here `c` is the index not the list that you are searching. Since you cannot iterate through an integer, you are getting that error.

```
>>> myList = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> for c,element in enumerate(myList):
...     print c,element
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

You are attempting to check if `1` is in `c`, which does not make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the OP's comment `It should print "t" if there is a 0 in a row and there is not a 1 in the row.`

change `if 1 not in c` to `if 1 not in row`

```
for c, row in enumerate(matrix):
    if 0 in row:
        print("Found 0 on row,", c, "index", row.index(0))
        if 1 not in row: #change here
            print ("t")
```

Further clarification: The `row` variable holds a single row itself, ie `[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]`. The `c` variable holds the index of *which* row it is. ie, if `row` holds the 3rd row in the matrix, `c = 2`. Remember that `c` is zero-based, ie the first row is at index 0, second row at index 1 etc.

Comment: The thing I am still confused about is when their are multiple rows with 0's in it. Would it do it for all of those rows?

Comment: @chingchong yes, it will print "Found 0 on row..." for every row that has a 0 on it. That is because we are looping on the rows in the  matrix via `for c, row in enumerate(matrix)`

Answer (score 2):

Well, if we closely look at the error, it says that we are looking to iterate over an object which is not iterable.
Basically, what I mean is  if we write `'x' in 1`, it would throw error .And if we write `'x' in [1]` it would return `False`

```
>>> 'x' in 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

>>> 'x' in [1]
False
```

So all we need to do it make the item iterable, in case of encountering this error.In this question, we can just make `c` by a list `[c]` to resolve the error. `if 1 not in [c]:`

Answer (score 1):

`c` is the row number, so it's an `int`.  So numbers can't be `in` other numbers.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  (When should it print `t`?)

Comment: It should print "t" if there is a 0 in a row and there is not a 1 in the row.

Comment: row does not look at the row that the 0 it has found is in though.

Comment: It looks to me like it should be the same row, but I don't have python installed on this computer and can't check myself.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate over 'c' which is just an integer, holding your row number.

> It should print "t" if there is a 0 in a row

Then just replace the c with the row so it says:

```
if 1 not in row:
```