# Python 3.2.2: Inexplicable fault in xmlrpc.client call - "argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, iteration, xml-rpc

Unlike previous  questions like [TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675231/typeerror-argument-of-type-int-is-not-iterable) there doesn't seem to be an immediately obvious indexing problem in my case.

In the code below, `testcfg.agents` is a list of hostnames and/or IP addresses, and `testcfg.port` is the port which `xmlrpc` calls should use. The `DSEvent` class models events in Active Directory, and `DSEvent.eventcommand` is a list containing a command and its parameters (passed through `xmlrpc` calls to an agent, which executes it using the `subprocess` module.)

```
# Create a list of agents to process events from
agent_list = []
for a in testcfg.agents:
    agent_list.append(xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://" + a + ':' + testcfg.port))

# Initial user creation:
for j in range(5):
    init_event = DSEvent(type = 'add', is_important = True)
    agent_eB = random.choice(agent_list)
    agent_eB.execute(init_event.eventcommand) # This line throws the fault described below!
```

The exact exception I'm getting is (with various tracebacks into the module stripped out):

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: "<class 'TypeError'>:argument of type 'int' is not iterable">
```

I can't understand where this fault might be coming from. While `init_event.eventcommand` is an iterable object (a list) I've passed and returned iterable objects via `xmlrpc` in other code without encountering this error. I've checked for accidental variable reuse, and I don't think that's the problem either. I'd really love some help here!

For reference, here's the full traceback for this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\randeventmaker\randeventmakerengine.py",
line 861, in <module>
    sproxy.execute(initializing_event.eventcommand)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1095, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1423, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1136, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1151, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1323, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 667, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: "<class 'TypeError'>:argument of type 'int' is
not iterable">
```

Comment: I would think that the "various tracebacks into the module" would tell you what exactly it's trying to iterate over that's not iterable, and would thus be a good hint to answering the question....

Comment: I've appended the full traceback to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this, at least partially. Apparently remote functions *only* take a tuple of arguments. Changing

```
agent_eB.execute(init_event.eventcommand)
```

to

```
agent_eb.execute((init_event.eventcommand,))
```

seems to have fixed this particular error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass in an iterable, such as an integer-list...

Comment: That's just it, though: `init_event.eventcommand` **is** an iterable object. It's a list containing commands, parameters and options for the `subprocess` module to work on, e.g. `['dsadd', 'user', new_user_fdn, '-ln', 'Bob', ... ]`.