# argument of type 'int' is not iterable Issue

Tags: python, selenium

What I trying to do is picking random integers from a value, for example: **1:32** will be an input, I will split by the **:** and then select a random value. Then Selenium will select the dropdown based on what value is returned.

My code:

```
# SELECT
if register_parts[3] == "SELECT":
    if register_parts[0] + '="' + register_parts[1] + '"' in self.driver.page_source:
        _select_value = ""
        if ":" in register_parts[2]:
            _select_value = self.get_random_value_between(register_parts[2]) 
            _select = Select(selenium_action)
            _select.select_by_visible_text(_select_value)
            self.write_to_debug_file("self.select_by_visible_text(" + _select_value + ") --> SELECT --> [ " + _select_value + " ]")
        else: 
            _select_value = register_parts[2]
            _select = Select(selenium_action)
            _select.select_by_visible_text(_select_value)
            self.write_to_debug_file("self.select_by_visible_text(" + _select_value + ") --> SELECT --> [ " + _select_value + " ]")
```

Additional function:

```
def get_random_value_between(self, input_values):
    ''' this function will return a random value between: x:x or 1:31 for example ... '''
    parts = input_values.split(':')
    return random.randrange(int(parts[0]), int(parts[1]))
```

The problem is on this line:

```
_select.select_by_visible_text(_select_value)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

From reading up, I *think* the issue lies in the fact I am doing:

```
if ":" in
```

I could be wrong. I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help on the issue would be appreciated. As far as I can see, the code should work, but I must be missing something. I have read a few threads on here regarding the error but it's still not sinking totally in.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
This includes the entire error message, not merely the one line of text.

Comment: You're trying to iterate over a scalar, such as `for i in 77`.  The `in` item has to be an iterable structure.  We can't see what values are going where, since you neglected to provide the problem line of code and the data being given to it.

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675231/typeerror-argument-of-type-int-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is correct. If the error is on `if` and not the `else`, then your passing an `Int` as an argument to a method that needs a text/str value.

Just try the following line:

```
_select.select_by_visible_text(str(_select_value))
```

Comment: Thank you guys, casting as a string was the answer, i could not see it clearly at time.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, cast `_select_value` as string before using `_select.select_by_visible_text`.

And recast as int values after the iteration.